# how to handle org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this pop up while executing the script:

> Modal dialog present: A script on this page may be busy, or it may
>   have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can
>   continue to see if the script will complete.

Can you please mention how to handle this by clicking continue button.Please find out the url below to see the screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXXFO.png

Comment: Patch work..Use Robot class..if that works for you

Comment: First concern should be: why is the script taking so long? You shouldn't be trying - in your tests - to work around genuine problems.

Comment: no robot is not working... i need to click on continue button

Answer (score 3):

It was because of default behavior of driver when it reaches to an alert. The default behavior - "ACCEPT", so alert was closed automatically. That's why `switchTo().alert()` couldn't find it.

At the time of creating `desirecapabilities` you can modify it.

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

To handle,

```
// untill timeout
try {  
   Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();
   alt.accept();
} catch(NoAlertPresentException noe) {
   // no alert.
}
```

Comment: No luck now also i am stuck in there. its not closing or handling it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following values in Firefox profile-

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("dom.max_chrome_script_run_time", 0);
profile.setPreference("dom.max_script_run_time",  0); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: What if OP needs his test to run in other browsers?

Comment: no its not working... actually i need to click on continue button

Comment: @RijoMon - Try setting the values to 999 as mentioned in this link

http://agilesoftwareautomationtesting.blogspot.in/2012/09/usual-problem-in-firefox-under-heavy.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. This worked for me in terms of pop outs when taking screenshots via the Web URL.

```
                        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                        String alertText = alert.getText();
                        System.out.println("ERROR: (ALERT BOX DETECTED) - ALERT MSG : " + alertText);
                        alert.accept();
                        File outputFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                        String imageDetails = "C://Images";
                        File screenShot = new File(imageDetails).getAbsoluteFile();
                        FileUtils.copyFile(outputFile, screenShot);
                        System.out.println("Screenshot saved: {}" + imageDetails);
                        driver.close();
```